# Set the camera on the CENTER of two points

Tags: android, eclipse, dictionary, camera, marker

Good Day Everyone!, I'am new on creating android application and I often having a hard time with the coding. I'm currently creating an android application about providing routes. I already have the two points and the route my problem is how can i set the camera on the center of these points?

Here is my code:

```
protected void setMarker(String locality, String country, double lat, double lng) {

        // Already two locations                
        if (markerPoints.size() > 1) {
            markerPoints.clear();
            map.clear();
        }

        // Adding new item to the ArrayList
        markerPoints.add(new LatLng(lat, lng));

        // Creating MarkerOptions
        MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions();

        // Setting the position of the marker
        options.position(new LatLng(lat, lng));

        /**
         * For the start location, the color of marker is GREEN and
         * for the end location, the color of marker is RED.
         */
        if (markerPoints.size() == 1) {
            options.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_AZURE))
                    .title(locality);
            options.snippet(country);

        } else if (markerPoints.size() == 2) {
            options.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_ORANGE))
                    .title(locality);
            options.snippet(country);
        }


        // Add new marker to the Google Map Android API V2
        map.addMarker(options);

        // Checks, whether start and end locations are captured
        if (markerPoints.size() >= 2) {
            LatLng origin = markerPoints.get(0);
            LatLng dest = markerPoints.get(1);

            // Getting URL to the Google Directions API
            String url = getDirectionsUrl(origin, dest);

            DownloadTask downloadTask = new DownloadTask();

            // Start downloading json data from Google Directions API
            downloadTask.execute(url);

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are some methods for finding the midpoint between two (or more) points: http://www.geomidpoint.com/calculation.html